# Input can't be empty

Tags: java, android

Inputs can't be empty

I tried to put the fields with the .equals("") method but it doesn't work

```
public class nuevaReceta extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHandler conn;
    AutoCompleteTextView txtNombreReceta;
    EditText txtPorciones, txttiempoPreparacion;
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView txtIngredientes, txtProcedimiento;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevareceta);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        conn = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext());

        Button btnGuardarReceta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarReceta);
        txtNombreReceta = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreReceta);
        txtPorciones = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPorciones);
        txtIngredientes = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIngredientes);
        txtProcedimiento = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPreparacion);
        txttiempoPreparacion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTiempo);

        this.setTitle("Nueva Receta");

        final Spinner spCategorias = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCategorias);
        ArrayAdapter spAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.categorias, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spCategorias.setAdapter(spAdapter);

        final Spinner spDificultad = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spDificultad);
        ArrayAdapter spAdapterD = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.dificultades, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spAdapterD.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spDificultad.setAdapter(spAdapterD);

        btnGuardarReceta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(txtNombreReceta.getText().toString().equals("")|txtPorciones.equals("")|txttiempoPreparacion.equals("")|txtIngredientes.equals("")){
                    System.out.print("Existen campos vacios!");
                }else {
                    String receta = txtNombreReceta.getText().toString();
                    int porcion = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(txtPorciones.getText()));
                    int tiempoP = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(txttiempoPreparacion.getText()));
                    String dificultad = spDificultad.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String ingredientes = txtIngredientes.getText().toString();
                    String preparacion = txtProcedimiento.getText().toString();
                    String categoria = spCategorias.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    int idCategoria = (int) spCategorias.getSelectedItemId(), fkCategoria = idCategoria + 1;
                    ;
                    int foto = 0;

                    switch (categoria) {
                        case "Bebidas":
                            foto = R.drawable.bebidas;
                            break;

                        case "Ensaladas":
                            foto = R.drawable.ensaladas;
                            break;

                        case "Pastas":
                            foto = R.drawable.pastas;
                            break;

                        case "Platos fuertes":
                            foto = R.drawable.platosfuertes;
                            break;

                        case "Sopa":
                            foto = R.drawable.sopas;
                            break;

                        case "Guarniciones":
                            foto = R.drawable.guarnicion;
                            break;

                        case "Postres":
                            foto = R.drawable.postres;
                            break;
                    }

                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("idUsuario", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    int idUsuario = sharedPreferences.getInt("idUsuario", 0);
                    conn.nuevaReceta(receta, fkCategoria, dificultad, tiempoP, porcion, ingredientes, preparacion, foto, idUsuario);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Receta guardada exitosamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
```

I need that the inputs can not be empty at the time of giving the button to add that performs the insert in the database. I have tried with the method .equals ("") but I do not know where to put it. Thank you

Comment: I suspect that using `txtPorciones.equals("")` instead of `txtPorciones.getText().toString().equals("")` (etc) has something to do with your problem

Comment: `txtPorciones.equals("")` will always be false. as EditText never can be equal to a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to know if a string is empty you better use `.isEmpty()`;

```
txtNombreReceta.getText().toString().isEmpty();
```

it will return `true` if string is empty

Comment: thank you friend, it worked, I managed to not be able to perform the insertion in the database if any of the inputs is empty, Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome , please consider my answer if it was correct :)

Comment: i did it jejebut im less than 15 reputation :)

Comment: i think you can accept answer but you can't upvote it :)